# Есть ли функция в JavaScript для удаление элемента?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли функция в JavaScript для удаление элемента?

```
function load() {
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('myschool'). /*Что дальше надо написать, что-бы удалить какой-то элемент*/
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
parent.removeChild( child );
```

где `parent` - это родительский элемент, а `child` - элемент который хотите удалить.

Так-же можно так

```
var child = document.body;
child.parentElement.removeChild( child );
```

Comment: Партизан, что ли? =)

    var child = document.body;
    child.parentNode.removeChild( child );

Answer (score 0):

Поробуй так:

```
element.removeNode(true);
```

пример:

```
document.getElementById('myschool').removeNode(true);
```

Comment: Нет такого метода - removeNode ( с точностью до спецификации DOM )

Comment: removeNode есть только в Internet Explorer.